# Algebra Proof including relative primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $c \in Z$ and $ \in a,b \in Z^{+}$ Let $c^2=ab$ suppose $(a,b)=1$

Show that there exist integers x,y s.t. $a=x^2$ and $b=y^2$

Any hints / directions will be helpful.

I know that I can write 
$(a,b)=1 \implies ax+by=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying $b$ in both members of $1=(a,b)$ we get, 
$$
b=(ab,b^2)=(c^2,b^2)=(c,b)^2.
$$
The same way we can get
$$
a=(a^2,ba)=(a^2,c^2)=(a,c)^2
$$

Comment: so $(a,c)^2=(ax+cy)^2=a$?

Comment: So we can take $x=(c,b)$ and $y=(a,c)$. We do not need the expression $ax+by=1$.

Comment: all right thank you, I didn't know that you could multiply into the GCD like that

Comment: I am using this property: $(na,nb)=n(a,b)$, where $a,b,n$ are integers